# One emacs config for different systems

Tags: linux, emacs, config, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to figure out a good way to use one emacs config for different systems.
I'm using emacs on windows inside WSL for work, but also on my linux machine at home.

The different systems have different requirements, for example at home, I use the `exwm` package as my window manager. When using emacs though WSL however, I don't need that package, there are other cases, this is just an example.

I don't want to split my config into two seperate repos (one for linux, one for wsl) because there is a fair amount of code that would get duplicated and hence needed to be updated twice if something changes.

So far, I've come up with something like this:

```lisp
; Determine which OS we are on.
(if (string-match "Microsoft" (car (split-string (shell-command-to-string "uname -r"))))
    (setq ENV "wsl")
  (setq ENV "linux"))
```

I can then do something like this:

```lisp
(if (equal ENV "linux")
    (setq doom-font (font-spec :family "Cozette" :size 12))
  (setq doom-font (font-spec :family "Inconsolata" :size 18)))
```

However, I don't know if this is a good way or not. I'd appreciate any input on the subject matter.

Comment: [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/47782/11) over on Emacs Stack Exchange has some suggestions. Seems like checking the variable `operating-system-release` might be the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of different ways to achieve what you're after, the "right way" is mostly a matter of preference.

For instance, you could split your configuration up into three files:

1. A file for shared (platform-independent) configuration options
2. A file for WSL-specific configurations
3. A file for Linux-specific configurations

File #1 would be your standard [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) at the end of which you could insert some code to load either file #2 or #3 depending on what platform you're on:

```
(if (string-match-p "microsoft" operating-system-release)
    (load-file path-to-wsl-config-file)
  (load-file path-to-linux-config-file)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers @Thomas. I think the way you check the architecture is superior to mine. However I think I won't split up my config like you suggested. I'd rather structure my config in terms of topic (window manager, dev env, ...) instead of architecture. So i think I will I will inline the check where ever I need to.

But you're right in regards to there not being a right way. Certainly depends on how you want to stucture your config.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Glad I could help. It also really depends on how many differences you'll really end up having between the different architectures. If it's just a couple, using two different files might well be overkill. On the other hand, I'd probably not like seeing tons of `if` switches taking over my config file.